# Ubuntu laptop does not sleeps & auto entry of characters in terminal

Tags: suspend

Running Ubuntu 16.04 in my HCL me laptop.

Every time I suspend the laptop, the display gets off & it seems to go to suspend, but wakes up within 2 seconds.

If I kept the terminal open & suspend, it wakeup automatically in 2 seconds & the character "**~**" is automatically entered in the terminal repeatedly. I need to press backspace to stop the automatic entry of "~" in my terminal.
[image]
If I suspend from terminal using the command **sudo pm-suspend**, then it wakes up automatically in 2 seconds & the key combination "**^[[20~**" is automatically entered for sometimes & then again the same "**~**" get to repeatedly entered in my terminal automatically.Then i need to press backspace to stop it .
[image]

Actually the key combination "**^[[20~**" represents the function key F7, Fn+F7 to enable or denable the touchpad

**Evering happening automatically, I'm not pressing the keyboard here.**

Sleep works well in windows 7.
Problems even exits after clean install of ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Also installed ubuntu 12.04.3, same problem seems there.

The problem arise from ubuntu 14.04.
Any help to put my laptop in sleep/suspend, advanced thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had this problem on a Dell Latitude 5450 running Ubuntu  14.04 even with no console other user app running before the suspend.

I had it configured to not require my password on wake so I could return to my work without further ado.

I discovered that if I logged out then right back in before suspending, it would start staying suspended.  Would continue to stay suspended for a few days before redeveloping the spontaneous wakeups.

Haven't had this problem yet with 16.04 but have only been using it two days.